# Ansible doesn't recognize mvn command, but Maven is installed

Tags: linux, maven, ansible

I'm trying to run a maven project from Ansible Tower, but Ansible kepps giving me a 'mvn: command not recognized' error, mvn runs fine if I do it manually from command line on a Linux server

I had a similar issue trying to run Gradle from Ansible, however the solution for that did not work here. Previously, the issue was that I needed to set env variables when I ran the playbook. I have tried that here, but to no avail. I checked my path and can see the Maven path there.

I took Zeitounator's advice and tried to make the call from Ansible using the absolute path, and that worked. But, as he mentioned, this was just a test and not an actual solution.

- I added /bin to the PATH since it was previously missing for some
  reason
- I tried changing MAVEN_HOME to /opt/maven/bin/ in both the server and in the Ansible playbook
- I made sure that the M2_HOME variable is blank since I read that it can cause some issues if it's there

It seems that Ansible has no idea where to look for Maven and I'm not really sure how else to convey that information to it. I feel like this is a silly quirk of Ansible that has stupid easy solution, and that could be fixed if I had anything other than 'mvn: command not found' to work with.

Here is the call from my playbook:

```
- name: test mvn
    shell: mvn -version
    args:
      chdir: /opt/jenkins/batchtest/
    environment:
      MAVEN_HOME: /opt/maven/
      JAVA_HOME: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_162
```

and here is the result of getting the PATH:

```
-bash-4.2$ echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

Here is the output from mvn -version incase there's something here that I'm missing

```
-bash-4.2$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T13:49:05-06:00)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_202, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_202-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same user, having the same path, using the same shell, connecting on the same server ? What happens if you call the command with the absolute path ? (i.e. `/opt/maven/bin/mvn`) ?

Comment: So, calling the absolute path works fine, but that's really more of a band-aid fix than a solution.

Comment: I'm sure that I'm using the same user, same server etc. I'm using Ansible Tower to have most of that stuff pre-setup and I'm following the same process I used when I had to test a Gradle project earlier this week.

Comment: This was not a solution but a test: it just means `/opt/maven/bin` is not in your path as you thought when your are connecting with ansible with your default ansible shell params. Answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are launching your test commands above directly on the server with the **bash** shell.

Ansible `shell` module uses the **sh** shell by default (see [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html))

I have to take a guess here but I'm 99.9% sure that the maven bin path is added to your `PATH` variable in a bash specific init file, so it is not available when you are using sh.

You now have 2 solutions:

1. Change the way you declare your `PATH` so that both bash and sh pick the value. For system-wide setting, you can use `/etc/profile`. For user specific, using `~/.profile` should do the trick.
2. Change the shell ansible is using to bash so that your are in the exact same situation

```
- name: test mvn
  shell: mvn -version
  args:
    chdir: /opt/jenkins/batchtest/
    executable: /bin/bash
  environment:
    MAVEN_HOME: /opt/maven/
    JAVA_HOME: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_162
```

Comment: I wasn't able to make this work since access to config files is restricted, but I'll get in touch with the right people and get this sorted. You were correct that the PATH was not the same. when I ran echo $PATH in Ansible, it came back "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"

So for now, I am just going to call the absolute path until I can get someone with a higher pay-grade to adjust the PATH for me. 

I'm marking this as the answer because I am 99.9% sure that this will work once the config is fixed. Thanks for your help. :)